# Using JavaScript to make title pop out in webpage?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a webpage. Code can be found here:
https://jsfiddle.net/saTfR/43/

HTML:

```
<body>
    <img id="map" src="http://www.local-guru.net/img/guru/worldglow.png"
    alt="map">
</body>
    <div id="sidebar">
<div class="logo">
    <img id="logo" src="logo2.png" alt="Logo"> 
</div>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {font-family: Lucida Console; }
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 230px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #CD6A51;
}

 </style>
```

I want to insert some text which will have a "pop out" effect on top of the map image. How would I be able to do that?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "pop out effect"? Do you mean like a drop shadow?

Comment: @Maximillian Laumeister Something like the text slowly appearing on the webpage on top of the map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of your map image. I assume you want it in the "center" of your image even if you scroll to the right you still want it to stick there.

You can easily create this by using the fadeIn method (jquery)

Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<p class="text">asdfasdfaa</p>        
<img id="map" src="http://www.local-guru.net/img/guru/worldglow.png" alt="map"/>
<p class="text">asdfasdfaa</p>      


<div id="sidebar">
<div class="logo">
    <img id="logo" src="logo2.png" alt="Logo"> 
</div>
```

CSS: (adjust css to your needs)

```
* {font-family: Lucida Console; }
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 230px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #CD6A51;
}
.text{

    color:white;
    z-index:999;
    position:fixed;
    left:60%;
    font-size:25px;

}
```

JS
pop-up effect that you specified in the comment:

```
  $(".text").hide().fadeIn(2000);
```

Here is also the code for your header text to disappear once you scroll down. When you scroll up it will reappear again.

```
var mywindow = $(window);
var pos = mywindow.scrollTop();
mywindow.scroll(function() {
    if(mywindow.scrollTop() > pos)
    {
        $('.text').fadeOut();  
    }
    else
    {
        $('.text').fadeIn();
    }
    pos = mywindow.scrollTop();
 });
```

and here is the fiddle(updated) URL: https://jsfiddle.net/eugensunic/saTfR/48/

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. It works. However, I don't want the text to be shown when I scroll down because I will insert a menu on the left side which will scroll down to the different sections (where I will insert other text, pictures). I want the map image to always stay the same in the background. Should I ask this as a new question?

Comment: I've also decided to take off the coloured sidebar and add a menu which will be on top of the map image. Does this make sense?

Comment: Yes, you should post a new question because you obviously changed a lot of code(html, css).

Comment: I have updated the fiddle in my answer and also put the code inside of it. You can always refer to it now.